# How do I get Automatic Recovery to work with the Java RabbitMQ client?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am using the Java RabbitMQ client to make RPC-style calls to a remote system from multi-threaded code, and despite my best efforts I have been unable to get the [automatic recovery](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery) feature to work. In production everything falls over about once per day on average. Of course, I have failed to find a way of replicating this on a test setup.

Thus my question: Assuming that the automatic recovery features of the Java RabbitMQ client do actually work as advertised, I must be misunderstanding something fundamental. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

There are some similar-ish questions on here, but they generally have a later answer added saying something like *"Since version 3.3.0 you can use automatic recovery, which is a new feature of the Java client."* I have only been working with versions post-3.5.0, and hence I hope my question can be accepted as I intend it, which is very much *not* as a duplicate.

Yes, I know of [Lyra](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra#readme) - but if the only answer to my question is *'You should be using Lyra'* that suggests to me that my statement about *'assuming that the automatic recovery features of the Java RabbitMQ client do actually work as advertised'* may need some re-evaluation...

The documentation doesn't give a great deal to go on, which perhaps may be part of the problem. I have therefore boiled my production code down to a minimal (ish... but I don't see how I can really cut out much more and still expect a useful answer - but I apologise for the length) case which should show clearly what I am doing. The only things missing are the method that creates a TLS-enabled `ConnectionFactory` and the C# service that is on the other end of the RPC. Hopefully this will be sufficient for someone to give me some pointers.

In production, this code is stuffed with logging and also registers connection and channel recovery listeners just for the purpose of logging. In two months of logging, with the system having to be restarted due to failures in the RabbitMQ-related code roughly daily, *not once* do the logs show either of the recovery listeners or `handleRecoverOk` being called. What I see are calls to `handleCancel` followed by all subsequent operations on the thread failing either with timeouts or a `ConsumerCancelledException`.

In case it makes a difference, production is on Solaris 11. I have attempted to cause failures on demand in test cases on my Windows PC by closing the socket using TCPView, but that causes a call to `handleShutdownSignal` followed by an `AlreadyClosedException` - a rather different failure mode.

In my code `Consumer` is modelled on the deprecated `QueueingConsumer`, but attempting to support recovery. I can see that putting the poison object into the queue may scupper any chance of the call that is under way when the failure is detected working (as `nextDelivery` will probably be called and cause an exception before there is a chance for recovery to happen), but I would expect `handleRecoverOk` to remove the poison again at some point, leaving a fully-functional thread. That never seems to happen.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties;
import com.rabbitmq.utility.Utility;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;

public class RabbitMQCall {
    private final String requestQueueName;
    private final int maxRetries = 5;
    private final Connection connection;
    private volatile boolean closed = false;
    private final ThreadLocal<PerThreadDetails> perThreadDetails = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final static Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    // Method to run minimal, reduced-to-one-class example code.
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = setupTLSEnabledConnectionFactory();
        factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
        factory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
        RabbitMQCall rmqcall = new RabbitMQCall(factory, "call");
        String data = "{\"---METHOD---\":\"ECHO\",\"USERNAME\":\"Test\"}";
        while (true) {
            rmqcall.call(data, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
            System.out.println("OK");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of {@code RabbitMQCall} configured with the supplied information.
     * Automatic connection and topology recovery must be enabled on the {@code ConnectionFactory}
     * as this class makes no attempt to reconnect in case of errors.
     * @param connectionFactory the {@link com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory} specifying all the
     * details for the connection to the RabbitMQ server
     * @param requestQueueName the request queue name
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the {@code ConnectionFactory} has invalid settings
     * @throws IOException in case of error setting up the RabbitMQ connection
     * @throws TimeoutException in case of timeout setting up the RabbitMQ connection
     */
    public RabbitMQCall(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String requestQueueName)
            throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        this.requestQueueName = requestQueueName;
        connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Calls a remote method (passing the supplied data) using RabbitMQ with the specified timeout.
     * Up to the configured number of retries of the complete operation will be attempted before an
     * {@link Exception} is thrown.
     * @param data a textual representation of the data for the call
     * @param timeout the timeout to use when awaiting a response from the remote process, or
     * {@code null} to wait forever
     * @return a textual representation of the result or error
     * @throws NullPointerException if either argument is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code timeout} is negative
     * @throws Exception if there was a failure invoking the remote call (rather than in the
     * operation of the remote call itself)
     * @throws InterruptedException if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The
     * <i>interrupted status</i> of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.
     */
    public String call(String data, Duration timeout) throws Exception, InterruptedException {
        if (closed) {
            throw (new Exception("RabbitMQCall.call() cannot be called on a closed instance"));
        }
        if (timeout != null) {
            if (timeout.isNegative() || timeout.isZero()) {
                throw (new IllegalArgumentException("The timeout must be positive or null"));
            }
        }

        // See if this thread already has a channel set up, and create one if not.
        PerThreadDetails details = perThreadDetails.get();
        if (details == null) {
            details = new PerThreadDetails();
            try {
                details.channel = connection.createChannel();
                if (!(details.channel instanceof Recoverable)) {
                    throw (new AssertionError("Channel doesn't implement Recoverable"));
                }
                details.replyQueueName = details.channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
                details.consumer = new Consumer(details.channel);
                details.channel.basicConsume(details.replyQueueName, true, details.consumer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw (new Exception("Failed to set up RabbitMQ Channel: " + e, e));
            }
            perThreadDetails.set(details);
        }

        // Wrap the whole thing in a retry loop to handle timeouts.
        RETRY: for (int attempt = 0; attempt <= maxRetries; ++attempt) {
            String corrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            BasicProperties props = new BasicProperties.Builder()
                    .correlationId(corrId)
                    .replyTo(details.replyQueueName)
                    .build();

            // Encode the data with the appropriate character encoding into a byte array.
            ByteBuffer bb = CHARSET.encode(data);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bb.remaining()];
            bb.get(bytes);

            try {
                details.channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw (new Exception("Error publishing to RabbitMQ Channel: " + e, e));
            }

            // Loop receiving messages until we get the one we're waiting for.
            while (true) {
                Consumer.Delivery delivery = null;
                if (timeout != null) {
                    delivery = details.consumer.nextDelivery(timeout);
                } else {
                    delivery = details.consumer.nextDelivery();
                }

                if (delivery == null) {
                    break; // Break out of inner loop for the next iteration of the retry loop.
                }

                String response = new String(delivery.getBody(), CHARSET);

                // If response matches our request then we have what we're waiting for, so return.
                if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        throw (new Exception("Timeout waiting for response from remote system via RabbitMQ"));
    }

    public void close() {
        if (!closed) {
            closed = true;
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.abort();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Consumer extends DefaultConsumer {
        private static final Delivery CANCELLED = new Delivery(null, null, null);
        private static final Delivery SHUTDOWN = new Delivery(null, null, null);
        private final BlockingQueue<Delivery> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        private volatile ShutdownSignalException shutdownException;

        Consumer(Channel channel) {
            super(channel);
        }

        Delivery nextDelivery() throws InterruptedException, ShutdownSignalException,
                ConsumerCancelledException {
            Delivery d = queue.take();
            return processDelivery(d);
        }

        Delivery nextDelivery(Duration timeout) throws InterruptedException,
                ShutdownSignalException, ConsumerCancelledException {
            Delivery d = queue.poll(timeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return processDelivery(d);
        }

        private Delivery processDelivery(Delivery d) {
            if (d == SHUTDOWN) {
                queue.add(SHUTDOWN);
                throw (Utility.fixStackTrace(shutdownException));
            }
            if (d == CANCELLED) {
                throw (new ConsumerCancelledException());
            }
            return d;
        }

        @Override public void handleConsumeOk(String consumerTag) {
            super.handleConsumeOk(consumerTag);
        }

        @Override public void handleCancel(String consumerTag) {
            queue.add(CANCELLED);
        }

        @Override public void handleCancelOk(String consumerTag) {
            queue.add(CANCELLED);
        }

        @Override public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
            if (shutdownException != null) {
                throw (Utility.fixStackTrace(shutdownException));
            }
            queue.add(new Delivery(envelope, properties, body));
        }

        @Override public void handleRecoverOk(String consumerTag) {
            super.handleConsumeOk(consumerTag); // Set the new tag in the only way we can.
            while (queue.contains(CANCELLED)) { // Remove our poison message(s).
                queue.remove(CANCELLED);
            }
        }

        @Override public void handleShutdownSignal(String consumerTag, ShutdownSignalException sig) {
            shutdownException = sig;
            queue.add(SHUTDOWN);
        }

        private static class Delivery {
            private final Envelope envelope;
            private final AMQP.BasicProperties properties;
            private final byte[] body;

            Delivery(Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
                this.envelope = envelope;
                this.properties = properties;
                this.body = body;
            }

            public byte[] getBody() {
                return body;
            }

            public Envelope getEnvelope() {
                return envelope;
            }

            public AMQP.BasicProperties getProperties() {
                return properties;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class PerThreadDetails {
        public Channel channel;
        public String replyQueueName;
        public Consumer consumer;
    }
}
```

I have been using the artefact amqp-client 3.5.6 for most of this testing,
although the latest 3.5.7 doesn't seem to change anything.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
factory.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
 factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
 factory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
 factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);
 factory.setExceptionHandler(new DefaultExceptionHandler());
 factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(360);`
```

add it before you open connection. One more advise, do not use deprecated classes, use `DefaultConsumer` instead of `QueingConsumer`

Comment: QueueingConsumer is not deprecated.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/